# How to "unminify" a Fedora Docker Container?

Tags: docker, installation, fedora

I'm using Docker on my M1 Mac Mini to run Linux environments to test my programs.

I pulled all my images using `docker pull ...`, and I've only used official images (official Ubuntu, official Fedora).

When I run some important commands in the Ubuntu container image, it prompted me to "unminify" the image - I checked the command, and its full path is `/usr/local/sbin/unminimize`. Once I run this command, a full command-line Ubuntu "operating system" is setup.

For some reason (Ubuntu seem to have trouble with QEMU-SPARC64 user-space emulator), I'm switching to Fedora. My question being: how to unminify a Fedora image? Is there a "meta"-package to install or some command to run?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think "unminify" is a standard term around Docker.  Can you edit the question to provide a [mcve] – what is in your Dockerfile and how are you launching the container – as well as the exact complete error you're getting?

Comment: @DavidMaze Added. Probably it's some term specific to Ubuntu in Docker.

Comment: For those voting to close basing on the argument that this is about "general computing hw&sw", I'd argue that setting up Docker image isn't as general as regular operating system installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not some specific "meta"-package you're looking for. It's "Package Group", and they can be queried using `dnf grouplist`.

You seem to need "Minimal Install" package group for starters, it can be installed with

```
dnf install @"Minimal Install"
```